# Centos BIND server: Unable to start named daemon

Tags: bind, centos6, named-conf, rndc

I've installed a fresh Centos server and installed bind and bind-utils to it.
The content of `/etc/named.conf` is:

```
# create new
 options {
    directory "/var/named";
    allow-query { localhost; 10.1.2.0/24; };
    allow-transfer { localhost; 10.1.2.0/24; };
    recursion yes;
};
controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { rndckey; };
};
view "internal" {
    match-clients {
        localhost;
        10.1.2.0/24;
    };
    zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
    };
    zone "amadeus.netvision" IN {
        type master;
        file "amadeus.netvision.lan";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "0.0.10.db";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "localdomain" IN {
        type master;
        file "localdomain.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "localhost.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.local";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "255.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.broadcast";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.zero";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
};
view "external" {
    match-clients { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
    recursion no;
    zone "amadeus.netvision" IN {
        type master;
        file "amadeus.netvision.wan";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
};
include "/etc/rndc.key";

# allow-query ⇒ query range you permit
# allow-transfer ⇒ the range you permit to transfer zone info
# recursion ⇒ allow or not to search recursively
# view "internal" { *** }; ⇒ write for internal definition
# view "external" { *** }; ⇒ write for external definition
# For How to write for reverse resolving, Write network address reversely like below.
# 10.1.2.0/24
# network address⇒ 10.1.2.0
# range of network⇒ 10.1.2.0 - 10.0.0.255
# how to write⇒ 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa
# 172.16.0.80/29
# network address⇒ 172.16.0.80
# range of network⇒ 172.16.0.80 - 172.16.0.87
# how to write⇒ 80.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa
```

When I try to start the named daemon i get the following error:

```
[root@srv ~]# service named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named: 
Error in named configuration:
/etc/named.conf:9: unknown key 'rndckey'
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@srv ~]#
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I've created the rndc.key using the next command:
`rndc-confgen -a -c /etc/rndc.key` and it created the key but I still get the same error.
The file is present in the correct path: `/etc/rndc.key` and it's included in the `/etc/named.conf` file.

Comment: What does /etc/rndc.key look like? (you may want to blank out the secret)

Comment: I bet it's an ordering issue.  Try moving the `include "/etc/rndc.key";` line to the top of the file.  I think that at the time you're trying to reference the key it has been defined yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file `/etc/rndc.key` and see which is the name of the key. For example:

```
key "rndc-key" {
```

This name should be be specified in `named.conf`

```
keys { rndc-key; };
```

Comment: Do I have to create zone files or are they created automatically?

Comment: For localhost they may be installed with bind but for your domain you have to create zone files.

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the above symptom.

While my case was slightly different and this isn't the exact answer to the above question, hopefully this might help someone out...

In my case I had specified the key inside of the options block which is incorrect.

The **key** statement must be defined outside of any other statement (like the options statement block) in the *named.conf* config file.

ie the following is **incorrect**:

```
options {
    ...
    include "/etc/rndc.key";
};
```

The following is correct:

```
options {
    ...
};        
include "/etc/rndc.key";
```